Quantifier Free formula for $\exists\; x\; ( y=x^2) $
The formula $\exists\; x \;(y=x^2) $ is not equivalent to a quantifier-free formula in $(\mathbb{Q},+,\cdot,0,1) $ since a quentifier-free formula in this structure defines a set which is finite or co-finite.
How to show that it is also not equivalent to a quantifier-free formula in the structure $(\mathbb{Q},+,\cdot,0,1,<) $ ? (This is part of an exercise in Marker's Book)

Use the same sort of reasoning: can you make a guess (and then verify it!) what sets are QF-definable in the rationals with order? (HINT: it may help to first think about $(\mathbb{R};+,\cdot,0,1,<)$, which is a very different structure but has very similar quantifier-free behavior ...)

Without order, they are boolean combinations of zero sets of polynomials and hence finite or co-finite. with order, one can have sets of the form ${a\mid p(a)>0}$ for some polynomial $p$. But I cant figure it out...

Ok I think I got it, it must be a finite union of intervals?
